# Is there a way to clear the table (listObject) content and resizing it one column?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to reset a table (listObject) via VBA. I tried it in two ways:

**Idea 1: Clear table content and resize the table to one column**

```
 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblExample")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
        Dim numColumns As Long: numColumns = .ListColumns.Count
        If numColumns > 1 Then
               .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Delete 'Last statement
        End If
End With
```

The problem: When evaluating the last statement I get the runtime '438' error stating something like: 'Object does not support this Property or Method.'

**Idea 2: Delete the table and make a new one**

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
If .ListObjects.Count = 1 Then
           .ListObjects(1).Delete
           .ListObjects.Add(Destination:=.Range("I1:I105")).Name = "tblExample"
End If
End With
```

The problem: The new table is placed at a random location (= selected cell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tblExample")
    .Resize .Range.Resize(ColumnSize:=1)  ' resize entire table to only first column
End With
```

`ListObjects("tblExample").Resize` expects the new range of the table.

`ListObjects("tblExample").Range` gives the old range of the table and `.Resize(ColumnSize:=1)` resizes the old range to only one column.

---

Are you sure you mean `ActiveWorkbook`?

- `ActiveWorkbook` the workbook that is on top (has focus).
  can be any workbook the user clicks on while the macro is running.
- `ThisWorkbook` the workbook the VBA code is written in.
  is a defined workbook that never changes.

In most cases you should avoid `ActiveWorkbook` as it can change by a single mouse click and use `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of the subtelty `ThisWorkbook` vs `ActiveWorkbook` yet... I'm gonna fix this throughout my Workbook...